# When was the phrase "It's quiet, a little too quiet" first used?

Tags: dialogue, first-appearance, trope

> "*It's quiet, a little too quiet.*"

We have all heard this famous line being used in many movies.

What was the first movie to use this popular phrase?

Comment: I would appreceate some feedback on why the downvotes? I think this is a valid question about movies and it could help other users as well.

Comment: TBH, I fully expected this would be a dupe of an existing question. It doesn't actually appear to be. Maybe that's why? [I didn't dv btw]

Comment: I searched it, there wasn't anything about it, so I asked and honestly didn't expect the downvotes at all, I think it's an interesting question

Comment: There's a whole page on it at [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ItsQuietTooQuiet). I guess the points will go to the first person to nail which of those examples is the earliest ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin That's why I would love if _TV Tropes_ organized its info by date...

Comment: I think its from a John Wayne movie. "The Lucky Texan". If not it has to be an even older western

Answer (score 1):

According to ["TVTropes"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ItsQuietTooQuiet)

> Said word for word in Drums Along the Mohawk, right before the Tories launch their final assault on the fort

Drums Along the Mohawk is a film from 1939, which is later than "The Lucky Texan" mentioned by [Leigh](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/56262/leigh) in a comment (1934)

Comment: That was a quick answer.  A little too quick.

Comment: @SDH I see what you did there :)  I looked through other tropes but none were as early as this one, even Gone with the Wind is mentioned there but it is roughly the same time frame as the Drums Along the Mohawk

Comment: That was strictly a joke, not a criticism. :)